# Problem with Blender on Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: nvidia, cuda, blender

I have an Nvidia Geforce 1050 ti graphics card on my laptop and am running 19.10.

The proprietary driver was installed along with 19.10.  I have confirmed through through "additional drivers" that the laptop is using the nvidia 435 driver.  When I run "lspci | grep NVIDIA" i get confirmation that the card is recognized, but when I run "nvidia-smi" i get "NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDI driver.  Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running"

The NVIDIA Xserver lists the Nvidia card.

When I try to set up the CUDA rendering device in Blender 2.8 preferences, I get the error message "no compatible GPUs found"

I think the driver is installed and seen and the graphics card is recognized but can't use it in Blender. I am a linux newbie and have not been able to find a fix for this problem.  Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

So the step I was missing was to confirm password and enroll MOK when rebooting.  I reinstalled the Nvidia driver, rebooted and chose to enroll MOK during the restart, supplied my password and all is working now.  The need to do this wasn't clear to me and I was using a 2nd monitor which did not display anything until after the option to take this step had disappeared from the built in laptop monitor.